# How to plot a delta function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dirac-delta, fourier-transform

How to plot this function in Matlab:

$S(f)=1+\frac{1}{4}(\delta(f+2f{_1})+\delta(f-2f{_1})-\delta(f+2f{_2})+\delta(f-2f{_2}))$

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: It is better to treat the Dirac delta as a distribution not as a function. Wht is more its definition makes impossible the fact of plotting it, because for $\delta(0)$ its value is infinite at $x=0$ and $0$ otherwise. On the contrary, you can plot its integral, since the delta is defined under the integral sign.

Comment: If you are asking how to deal with your expression $$\delta(f(x)) = \delta(f'(x)\,x) = \frac{1}{|f'(x)|}\delta(x)$$

Comment: @HBR Thanks for your explanation. I just study electronics so my mathematical understanding is not perfect. But isn't there any chance to plot these "$\delta$" impulses? I would expect four impulses with a height of $+/-\frac{1}{4}$ at 2f1 and 2f2.

Comment: Okay, i know understand what you want. You cannot plot any delta, but you can plot an approximation, let me describe you how to deal with it in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "delta" function will be a limitting square impulse
$$\delta(x_0) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\left[\mathcal{H}(x_0-\epsilon)-\mathcal{H}(x_0+\epsilon)\right]$$
Where $\mathcal{H}(x)$ is the heaviside function, defined in matlab as "heaviside(x)".
Because you want an approximation of the Dirac delta, fix the parameter $\epsilon$, as tiny you want, and plot the function of $x$
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\left[\mathcal{H}(x-x_0-\epsilon)-\mathcal{H}(x-x_0+\epsilon)\right]$$
That in matlab writes:
$$ f= (heaviside(x-x0-eps)-heaviside(x-x0+eps))/(2*eps)$$
$$plot(x,f)$$
Once defined $x0$ ans $eps$. The height of this impulses is not $1$, but its integral.

Summing up, if you want an impulse with size $1/4$ (but not height, remember that) at $x_0$ you have to write 
$$ f_{1/4}=\frac{1}{4}(heaviside(x-x0-eps)-heaviside(x-x0+eps))/(2*eps)$$